# What causes signal 'SIGILL'?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, porting

I'm porting some C++ code to Android using NDK and GCC. The code basically runs. At one point, when debugging in Eclipse, the call

```cpp
Dabbler::Android::Factory* pFactory = new Dabbler::Android::Factory;
```

causes this error:

```
Thread [1] (Suspended: Signal 'SIGILL' received. Description: Illegal instruction.) 
    1 <symbol is not available> 0x812feb44
```

What does that mean? Has the compiler generated illegal code for some reason? I have a breakpoint in the constructor (which does nothing), and it's not hit. I have already done a full rebuild.

What could I be doing wrong to cause this problem?

Answer (score 57):

Make sure that all functions with non-void return type have a `return` statement.

While some compilers automatically provide a default return value, others will send a SIGILL or SIGTRAP at runtime when trying to leave a function without a return value.

Comment: You have no idea to what lengths I went searching for a reason behind SIGILL (QT + Android) just to find a missing return statement in a function (inspired by your reply). Thank you.

Comment: @Vega4 What compiler you were using? Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

It means the CPU attempted to execute an instruction it didn't understand.  This could be caused by corruption I guess, or maybe it's been compiled for the wrong architecture (in which case I would have thought the O/S would refuse to run the executable).  Not entirely sure what the root issue is.

Comment: Another cause of execing an invalid instruction is jumping to an address that isn't in the program area.

Comment: Weird, I got this, when I compiled with clang, but it worked fine with gcc

Answer (score 27):

It could be some un-initialized function pointer, in particular if you have corrupted memory (then the bogus vtable of C++ bad pointers to invalid objects might give that).

BTW `gdb` watchpoints & tracepoints, and also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) might be useful (if available) to debug such issues. Or some [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer).

Comment: For me, I wasn't returning any value from a function that was supposed to return an int. So somewhat related to this answer. No idea how it managed to compile.

Answer (score 6):

[LeetCode](http://leetcode.com)'s online compiler and dev environment generates `SIGILL` errors for mistakes that do not generate the same error in my desktop IDE.

For example, array access with an out-of-bounds index:

```
["foo", "bar"][2]
```

LeetCode's compiler shows only the error:

> Runtime Error
> process exited with signal `SIGILL`

in a local Xcode playground this same code instead results in [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70371234/xcode-playground-how-to-use-thread-return-x-to-return-to-the-state-before-e):

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x18f2ea5d8).
> The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

Only in a full Xcode project compilation and run does it report the actual error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range