# What happens when you execute an instruction that your CPU does not support?

Tags: linux, x86-64, avx

What happens if a CPU attempts to execute a binary that has been compiled with some instructions that your CPU doesn't support.  I'm specifically wondering about some of the new AVX instructions running on older processors.

I'm assuming this can be tested for, and a friendly message could in theory be displayed to a user.  Presumably most low level libraries will check this on your behalf.  Assuming you didn't make this check, what would you expect to happen?  What signal would your process receive?

Comment: [What causes signal 'SIGILL'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7901867/608639) and friends. As far as I know, `SIGILL` is raised on all Linux platforms, including i386, x86_64, ARM, Aarch32, Aarch64 and MIPS.

Comment: *"Presumably most low level libraries will check this on your behalf."* Uh, I don't think so. Most low-level libraries that use potentially unsupported instructions are doing so for speed above all else. It is the responsibility of high-level code to verify whether those instructions are supported *before* calling down to the low-level code. Use the `CPUID` instruction (exposed as an intrinsic in most compilers) to verify that the required instruction set is supported *before* executing them, thus avoiding any risk of an invalid instruction exception. Display the friendly error message then.

Comment: Halts and catches fire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A new instruction can be designed to be "legacy compatible" or it can not.
To the former class belong instructions like [`tzcnt`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/TZCNT.html) or `xacquire` that have an encoding that produces valid instructions in older architecture: `tzcnt` is encoded as
[`rep bsf`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BSF.html) and `xacquire` is just `repne`.
The semantic is different of course.

To the second class belong the majority of new instructions, AVX being one popular example.
When the CPU encounters an invalid or reserved encoding it generates the *#UD* (for *UnDefined*) exception - that's interrupt number 6.

The Linux kernel set the [IDT](http://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Descriptor_Table) entry for *#UD* early in [`entry_64.S`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#L850):

```
idtentry invalid_op         do_invalid_op           has_error_code=0
```

the entry points to `do_invalid_op` that is generated with a macro in [`traps.c`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c#L289):

```
DO_ERROR(X86_TRAP_UD,     SIGILL,  "invalid opcode",        invalid_op)
```

the macro `DO_ERROR` generates a function that calls `do_error_trap` in the same file ([here](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c#L282)).

`do_error_trap` uses `fill_trap_info` (in the same file, [here](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c#L201)) to create a `siginfo_t` structure containing the Linux signal information:

```
case X86_TRAP_UD:
    sicode = ILL_ILLOPN;
    siaddr = uprobe_get_trap_addr(regs);
    break;
```

from there the following calls happen:

`do_trap` in [`traps.c`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c#L233)
`force_sig_info` in [`signal.c`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/signal.c#L1171)
`specific_send_sig_info` in [`signal.c`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/signal.c#L1140)

that ultimately culminates in calling the signal handler for `SIGILL` of the offending process.

---

The following program is a very simple example that generates an *#UD*

```
BITS 64

GLOBAL _start

SECTION .text

_start:

 ud2
```

we can use `strace` to check the signal received by running that program

```
--- SIGILL {si_signo=SIGILL, si_code=ILL_ILLOPN, si_addr=0x400080} ---
+++ killed by SIGILL +++
```

as expected.

---

As [Cody Gray commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44750258/what-happens-when-you-execute-an-instruction-that-your-cpu-does-not-support#comment76501377_44750258), libraries don't usually rely on SIGILL, instead they use a [CPU dispatcher](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-integrated-performance-primitives-intel-ipp-understanding-cpu-optimized-code-used-in-intel-ipp) or check the presence of an instruction explicitly.