# Need some help ORA-24550: signal received:

Tags: c++, oracle, aix, proc, tuxedo

This is my first question.If I have missed to add any information. Please let me know.

I am getting below error while executing a batch program.

```
ORA-24550: signal received: [si_signo=4] [si_errno=0] [si_code=30] [si_addr=0]
kpedbg_dmp_stack()+364<-kpeDbgCrash()+124<-kpeDbgSignalHandler()+680<-skgesig_sigactionHandler()+264<-__sighandler()<-00000000<-00000000
./PRMS_RlsRTS[231]: 53543194 Illegal instruction(coredump).

libdebug assertion "(framep->getGpr(STKP, &addr) == DB_SUCCESS && *nextStkpp == addr)" failed at line 1299 in file ../../../../../../../../../../../src/bos/usr/ccs/lib/libdbx/libdebug/modules/stackdebug/POWER/stackdb_FrameProgress.C

Illegal instruction in . at 0x0 ($t1)
0x00000000 00000000       Invalid opcode.
```

This is a pro *C program running it on AIX 7.1 with Oracle Client 12.1.

Comment: if you search your error, you'll find a great Q&A here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955099/ora-24550-signal-received-si-signo-6-error

Comment: @thatjeffsmith. I read the post, changed the ulimit to unlimited, but its still failing. Also requested DBA to disable Automatic Diagnostic Repository (ADR) Parameters. Will try it again.

Comment: [si_signo=4] SIGILL        4       Core    Illegal Instruction  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901867/what-causes-signal-sigill

Comment: You have a memory-corruption bug in your program. Sadly, it is not detected when it happens, only much later. A possible debugging tool is Electric Fence. It can be compiled/installed on AIX, but it is easier to use on Linux, (if your program can be compiled on Linux -- as it should be), it would be something like this: `ulimit -c unlimited; LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libefence.so myprogram; gdb myprogram core`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond: Thank you. I cannot compile it on Linux as it depends on lots of Tuxedo libraries which are not available on other servers. Please advise if you think its my application program which is causing this and not AIX/Oracle.

Comment: A random question: do you happen to call a PL/SQL stored procedure that returns a cursor as 'out' parameter?

Comment: No, We don't call PL/SQL procedure, instead we have cursor declared inside pro *c. EXEC SQL DECLARE cursor.

Comment: @user11953765 Some hints regarding Electric Fence: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html#Q0040