# Xcode Playground: How to "use `thread return -x` to return to the state before expression evaluation."

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground

I've typed a very simple error into an Xcode playground:

```swift
import UIKit
        
var greeting = "Hello, playground"

["foo", "bar"][2] // error
```

The console correctly prints the error:

> Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:580: Fatal error: Index out of range

However the Xcode Playground error pop-up instead says:

[image: The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.]

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x18f2ea5d8).
>
> The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

---

How do I "use `thread return -x`" in the Xcode playground, as directed? Where can I type this and what does the command do?

Is some kind of setting, such as Xcode exception breakpoints, mistakenly enabled in this Playground? Why is this error being displayed instead of the actual `Fatal error: Index out of range` underlying error?

---

<sup>NOTE: I know what the simple code issue is and can easily fix it. This question is about why that error message is being displayed, and how/if I can use `thread return -x` in the Playground.</sup>

Comment: Xcode Playground doesn't give us access to the debugger like Xcode does. Go to this link https://www.objc.io/issues/19-debugging/lldb-debugging/ and scroll down to "Thread Return" which will tell you what this specific LLDB command does.

Comment: Issue on [Swift Forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/thread-return-x-what-does-it-mean/11342) and bug [SR-8694](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8694).

Comment: I still have the issue, does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score -2):

I had same issue, so first I removed import uikit and then imported Foundation. It's worked for me.

Comment: What worked for you? What exactly are you saying was fixed by importing Foundation instead of UIKit? Please clarify your answer. As written it's unclear.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35519608)